# How do I solve this error installing Canvas LMS using Docker and quickstart?

Tags: docker, rubygems, canvas-lms

I am trying to use the Quick Start guide from Instructure to install Canvas LMS locally on my Mac (https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start).

The script fails at step 23 - see below. The point of the script is to automate everything, so I don't know how serious this is...I obviously googled the errors and didn't find anything conclusive. Maybe a memory problem (lack of memory)?

Help appreciated...

```
Step 23/28 : RUN bundle install --jobs 8   && yarn install --pure-lockfile
 ---> Running in ff461afd0818
/home/docker/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle (LoadError)
    from /home/docker/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
ERROR: Service 'webpack' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install --jobs 8   && yarn install --pure-lockfile' returned a non-zero code: 1
Andrew-MBP:script ajmccann$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I got a little further after I read [this](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2180). I added:

```
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/
RUN ln -s /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/
```

to the Dockerfile a couple of lines above where you get that error.

Comment: Thank you! I gave up and got access to someone else's Canvas for testing...seemed like it would be one nightmare after another...Good to know that was maybe the only blocker.

Comment: Actually this one thing and adding more space and memory to my VM seemed to fix it. Took a LONG while to create that image though.